# Rig not moving in keyframe mode, bone locations turned green

Tags: animation, keyframes

I did something that I thought was just putting in another keyframe for one of my IK bones, but not when I move to another keyframe to adjust the rig, it will not move the mesh. There's a keyframe marker on the timeline.

(*I think that's what that yellow diamond is*) and the bone locations on the left have turned green.

What does this mean and how do I get back to moving my bones?

[image]

Comment: your problem is not clear, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/  green means these bones have keyframes but not on the current frame

Comment: Consulting the docs https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/timeline.html confirms that the yellow diamond is indeed a keyframe marker.